# ember local storage adapter: how to get data and work on it

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, electron, ember-local-storage

I use Ember in combination with Electron.

As the user can define some settings for the app, I thought it was a elegant idea to store the settings data in local storage.

For that I use ember-local-storage adapter.

Storing, deleting and displaying this data works like a charm BUT
These settings should be used in some functions, so I want to get them out of the local storage.
I expected an array or JSON object- or even the same format as it is shown in local storage. But I only receive a huge abstract object ?!

This is what I want to store (e.g.):

```html
{"identifier":"identifier1","bid":"6653ggd245","name":"test1"}
{"identifier":"identifier2","bid":"kkhd7765vv","name":"test2"}
```

This is what is displayed in localstorage (dev tools):

```html
{"buttons":
  {"records":
    {"i7lvj":{"id":"i7lvj","identifier":"identifier1","bid":"6653ggd245","name":"test1"},"i80vm":{"id":"i80vm","identifier":"identifier2","bid":"kkhd7765vv","name":"test2"}
  }}}
```

This is how I tried to access the data:

```html
this.get('store').findAll('buttons').then(function(SavButtons){

      console.log(SavButtons);
 });// gett all stored buttons


this.get('store').findRecord('buttons','i7lvj').then(function(SavButtons){

      console.log(SavButtons.data);
 });// get specific button -> works
```

This data is the base to generate an params array to use for Promises for API requests.
What can I do to get this in a reusable structure ?
For example:
0:{record1}
1:{record2}

Or is there even a simpler/better way to store settings made by the user after the app is closed, maybe I am missing something.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try `toArray` method to convert into plain array. or use  `forEach` to traverse and build the required structure and store it using local storage adapter and retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that your model called "buttons"? You probably need to use

```
this.get('store').findAll('button')
```

Also, what you receive from store is [Ember.ArrayProxy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) or some other class extended from Ember.Array. It has special methods to work with elements, you should try those

Second, I don't think that Ember Data is good for settings. I find it much easier to create custom "settings" [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/services/) and use that. Let me share [my implementation](https://gist.github.com/GendelfLugansk/697757c5327de25d748d9001867e8139) that I use with node-webkit. It will not work for you "as is", but you might get an idea. I made it with support for both files and local storage (files for nw-app and storage for web-app), you can simplify `_persist` and `_restore` methods if you need just local storage.

Brief explanation of how it works: it's a basic service with modified `init`, `set` and `setProperties` methods. So when you call in your controller `this.get('settings').set('key', vale);`, settings will be persisted in local storage. And when service is initialized, settings will be loaded from storage to memory. One limitation: you must explicitly call `set` and `setProperties` methods of settings service, if you will use something like `this.set('settings.key', value);`, settings will not be persisted. The main advantage of separate service over ember data is that you don't need to create models for different types of settings, you can save any simple value or POJO.

Comment: Yes, it is called "buttons". I am very new to Ember and to be honest it is much more complex than I thought. I don't really get the meaning of models and when to use them. I have read several articles but it's only very basic stuff. Thanks so much for sharing! I will try that out on the weekend. All in all this is exactly what I need. I only want to persist store an JSON object with the user settings. I thought I use the models when they are even there... but maybe thats going to far for now :)

Comment: @HS_hendrix models was created for the same, as models in ORM (if you are familiar with backend development). Model represents some data structure, so it should be good for any user data. For example, in todo app you have model that represent each item. Idea is good, but on practice Ember Data is not flexible and sometimes makes your code more complicated.

Comment: @HS_hendrix Also, did you install ember inspector? It helps to debug such issues. For example you can see what ember data's store has now (if it has any records at all or no)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, ember inspector is installed and there the records are listed so beautiful :)